# React Router v6 issues with routes as child component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have my app routes in a file like this:

```
<Route path='/' element={<Home />}>
  <Route index path='/' element={<Feed />} />
  <Route path='friends' element={<Friends />}>
    <Route index element={<>asd</>} />
    <Route path='friend-request' element={<>12</>} />
    <Route path='blocked-friends' element={<>ccc</>} />
    <Route path='add-friends' element={<AddFriends />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="saved" element={<>Saved</>} /> */}
</Route>
```

This gets very messy and was thinking of creating separate sub routes components to make it neater like this:

```
<Route path='/' element={<Home />}>
  <Route index path='/' element={<Feed />} />
  <FriendsRoutes />
  <Route path="saved" element={<>Saved</>} /> */}
</Route>
```

Where `FriendsRoutes` is a component with these routes:

```
<Route path='friends' element={<Friends />}>
  <Route index element={<>asd</>} />
  <Route path='friend-request' element={<>12</>} />
  <Route path='blocked-friends' element={<>ccc</>} />
  <Route path='add-friends' element={<AddFriends />} />
</Route>
```

But when I do this I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [FriendsRoutes] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>
```

Any Idea how to solve this?

Comment: You could try wrapping it in a fragment: `<><FriendsRoutes/></>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to split your code/routes up, that's fine. The error is informing you that ***only*** `Route` and `React.Fragment` are valid children of the `Routes` component. The `FriendsRoutes` component *still* needs to be rendered on by a `Route` component.

Exmaple:

```
<Routes>
  ...
  <Route path='/' element={<Home />}>
    <Route index path='/' element={<Feed />}/>
    <Route path="/friends/*" element={<FriendsRoutes />} /> // *
    <Route path="saved" element={<>Saved</>} />
  </Route>
  ...
</Routes>
```

* The root path is `"/friends/*"` with a trailing wildcard `"*"` matcher so all descendent route paths can also be matched.

`FriendsRoutes` then needs to render the *now* descendent routes into another `Routes` component for route matching to occur.

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<Friends />} >
    <Route index element={<>asd</>} />
    <Route path='friend-request' element={<>12</>} />
    <Route path='blocked-friends' element={<>ccc</>} />
    <Route path='add-friends' element={<AddFriends />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit, the answer by @Drew Reese looks more standard, I'd go with that over what I've outlined here.

The FriendsRoutes component you are creating is not a `Route` component. It is its own type, and *contains* a `Route` component.

I think, off the top of my head, if you wanted this to work, you'd have to do one of the following:

### Array of `Route`s as children

```
const friendsRoutesArray = () => [
  <Route key="index" index element={<>asd</>} />,
  <Route key="friend-request" path="friend-request" element={<>12</>} />,
  <Route key="blocked-friends" path="blocked-friends" element={<>ccc</>} />,
  <Route key="add-friends" path="add-friends" element={<div />} />
];
```

```
<Route path='/'  element={<Home />}>
  <Route index path='/' element={<Feed />}/>
  <Route path='friends' element={<Friends />} >
    {friendsRoutesArray()}
  </Route>
  <Route path="saved" element={<>Saved</>} /> */}
</Route>
```

### Invoke the function, returning the `Route`

```
const FriendsRoutes = () => (
  <Route path="friends" element={<div />}>
    <Route index element={<>asd</>} />
    <Route path="friend-request" element={<>12</>} />
    <Route path="blocked-friends" element={<>ccc</>} />
    <Route path="add-friends" element={<div />} />
  </Route>);
```

```
<Route path='/'  element={<Home />}>
  <Route index path='/' element={<Feed />}/>
  {FriendsRoutes()}
  <Route path="saved" element={<>Saved</>} /> */}
</Route>
```